# Django Choices As Uppercase With Spaces

Tags: django, django-models

I am having an issue where when using Django choices in a model, it will save the value with lowercase and no spaces.  I have to import alot of data into the database and I want it to be formatted with capitalized letters and spaces.  I have tried changing the value that saves to have spaces and capital letters but it doesn't appear to work.

```
class Station(models.Model):
FORMAT_CHOICES = (
    ('AC', 'AC'),
    ('Adult Hits', 'Adult Hits'),
    ('CHR', 'CHR'),
    ('Classic Country', 'Classic Country'),
    ('Classic Hits', 'Classic Hits'),
    ('Country', 'Country'),
    ('Gospel', 'Gospel'),
    ('Hot AC', 'Hot Ac'),
    ('News Talk', 'News Talk'),
    ('Oldies', 'Oldies'),
    ('Rock', 'Rock'),
    ('Sports', 'Sports'),
    ('Urban', 'Urban'),
    ('Urban AC', 'Urban AC')
)
TIMEZONE_CHOICES = (
    ('Alaska', 'Alaska'),
    ('Central', 'Central'),
    ('Eastern', 'Eastern'),
    ('Mountain', 'Mountain'),
    ('Western', 'Western'),
)
market = models.ForeignKey(Market, verbose_name=u'Market')
call_letters = models.CharField('Call Letters', max_length=40)
frequency = models.CharField('Frequency', max_length=40)
state = models.CharField('State', max_length=40)
region = models.ForeignKey(Region, verbose_name=u'Region')
timezone = models.CharField('Timezone', max_length=40, choices=TIMEZONE_CHOICES)
format = models.CharField('Format', max_length=40, choices=FORMAT_CHOICES)
positioning = models.CharField('Positioning Statement', max_length=100)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.call_letters
```

What is the best way to accomplish storing the model data for choice fields with capitalized first letters of words and with spaces?

Comment: why would you want to do that? It would make things really complicated.. querying would be much difficult with that kind of fields in the database... If you don't mind I'd like to know what is the reason behind this particular speculation?

Comment: I had a large amount of data to import that is not formatted to the lowercase no space specs.  Also since the data is all an API that shows the nice version name, I didn't really think about needing queries within Django.  I guess maybe it's best to spend the time to convert the csv values to lowercase then.

Comment: I'd recommend that... better to prepared than suffer.. right?

Comment: I did that.  The strange thing is after applying the migrations my updated choices aren't showing properly in the django admin.  Do those get cached somehow?

Comment: Nevermind, I had to restart apache.  Thanks for the tips.